# Proper Design for Java Interfaces with Respect to Exceptions

Tags: java, exception, interface

**I'm trying to understand how to properly define interfaces in Java with respect to how exceptions are treated in the language (and runtime).**

NOTE: *Perhaps this question has already been asked and adequately answered, but my search of SO (and other sites) didn't turn up anything that directly addressed the design question and the trade-offs I present. I'll happily delete this question if an analogous one can be found that answers my question. I apologize in advance for the long-winded question, but I wanted to state the problem as clearly as possible. I'm also aware of the [controversy around checked exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html), but since I am not in a position to change the language and must still work within it, I'd like to select the approach(es) that will cause the least pain in the long term.*

The recurring problem I encounter is when I try to define my own interfaces I am faced with the choice of how to specify which (if any) exceptions are allowed to the members of the interface. The trouble is that I have no way of knowing which exceptions are meaningful, since I don't know ahead of time what all of the possible implementations for my interface might be. For the sake of an example, suppose we have the following interface:

```
// purely hypothetical interface meant to illustrate the example...
public interface SegmentPartition {
    // option 1
    bool hasSegment(Segment s);
    // option 2
    void addSegment(Segment s) throws Exception;
    // option 3
    bool tryAddSegment(Segment s) throws TimeoutException, IOException, ParseException, XmlException, SQLException;
    // option 4
    void optimizeSegments() throws SegmentPartitionException;
}
```

What exception types should this interface declare upfront? The options I see are:

1. don't declare any exception, implementations can only throw `RuntimeException`'s
2. declare each method as throwing `Exception`
3. try to anticipate every possible exception type that makes sense for this interface and declare them as the throwable exceptions.
4. create my own exception type (e.g. `SegmentException`) and require that it be thrown with an inner exception as needed for additional detail.

**There are problem with each of these approaches, and it's not entirely clear what all of the tradeoffs are likely to be, I've mentioned a few for each case. Ideally, I don't want any exceptions to be thrown by the implementation, but that's not always a practical restriction.**

For **option 1**, the trouble is that many of the exception types that may be thrown are not derived from RuntimeException (for instance IOException or TimeoutException). I could, of course, add these specific exceptions to the interface and then allow other RuntimeExceptions to be thrown as well, but what about user-defined exceptions then? This seems like a poor option.

With **option 2** we end up with an interface that seems like it could result in any exception whatsoever (which I suppose is true), and provides no guidance to implementors on what should actually be thrown. The interface is no longer self documenting. Worse yet, every call site of this interface must either be declared as throwing Exception or wrap each call to methods of this interface in `try{} catch(Exception)`, or create a block that catches Exception and tries to suss out whether it was thrown by the interface implementation or something else in that block. Yuck. Alternatively, the code that uses this interface could catch the specific exceptions that the implementations might throw, but then it violates the purpose of having an interface to begin with (in that it requires the caller to know the runtime type of the implementation). In practice, this is the option closest to what most other languages I know take with regards to exceptions (C++, C#, Scala, etc).

With **option 3** I must specifically anticipate the potential implementations that could be defined for my interface, and declare the exceptions most appropriate for them. So if I anticipate that my interface may be implemented over a remote, unreliable connection I would add TimeoutException, if I anticipate it may be implemented using external storage I would include IOException, and so on. I am almost certainly likely to get it wrong ... which means that I am going to continually churn the interface as new implementation paradigms surface (which, of course, breaks all existing implementations and requires them to declare non-sensical exceptions as being thrown). A further problem with this approach is that results in ugly, repetitive code ... particularly for large interfaces with many methods (yes, sometimes these are needed) which then need to be repeated at each implementation point.

With **option 4** I must create my own exception type, together with all of the baggage that accompanies that (serializability, nesting and inner exceptions, coming up with a reasonable hierarchy, etc). What seems to inevitably happen here is that you end up with one exception type for each interface type:  InterfaceFoo + InterfaceFooException. Aside from the code bloat this entails, the real problem is that the exception type doesn't mean anything ... it's just a type used to bundle together all of the error conditions for the particular interface. In some cases, perhaps, you can create a few subclasses of the exception type to indicate particular modes of failure, but even that is questionable.

**So what is the right thing to do here, in general?** I realize there may not be a cut and dry rule, but I'm curious about what experienced Java developers choose do.

Thanks SO.

Comment: I'd advise against `throws Exception` whenever possible. If you don't know what should be thrown and handled, declare nothing at all, and let the implementations throw runtime exceptions. These should be appropriately documented for all implementations.

Comment: So what should implementors do if they need to throw TimeoutException (which is NOT a runtime exception)?

Comment: The context is relevant. If you know what the implementations might do, you can *predict* some specific exceptions to be thrown. These should make sense at the interface level. It makes sense that a method related to sockets or files throw an `IOException`, for instance. If you really can't predict what the implementations might do, roll your own exception type, in order to wrap these core checked exceptions. That's what I'd do, in general.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you advise against `throws Exception`? Here's an example where it feels like it would be the best option:
`public interface IPredicate<T> { bool apply(T item) throws Exception; }` If you don't use `throws Exception` then using `IPredicate` as an anonymous inner class becomes more painful than it already is.

Comment: You mostly pointed out the reasons yourself. An interface should be self-documenting. You should be able to read an interface and understand it. With `throws Exception` you are telling the clients of your interface *«in the normal course of events, it is expected that this method might throw **any** exception, and I want you to handle it»*. This leads to poorly maintainable code (`catch Exception`), and may also *clog* any attempt of formal verification of the code.

Comment: Of course, at the end of the day, it might boil down to how much code you can endure writing, and how to write it (anonymous vs regular inner class, *etc*.). For your `IPredicate<T>` I'd still avoid `throws Exception`. Not many predicates might incur exceptions, and, in my point of view, they certainly don't in the bigger picture. If some predicate actually needs to throw a checked exception in its implementation, wrap it in a runtime exception, or catch it and define in the documentation an appropriate return value, whatever makes more sense in the specific environment.

Comment: Throwing exception from an IPredicate is imho diametrically to the common purpose of that interface. It should establish a two valued logic - either an item satisfies the condition or not. Adding throws Exception changes that into the dreaded three valued logic - an item satisfies the condition, does not satisfy it or you do not know whether it does or not. I would say that is a bad design.

Comment: @Pyranja While I agree the interface intends to provide a true/false result, I don't think you can escape from the "ternary logic" problem even if the interface doesn't use checked exceptions - after all, RuntimeExceptions can be thrown from anywhere. The practical problem that arises is that some types you may want to use from within anonymous implementations of `IPredicate` may throw checked exceptions. So what happens then? Do you swallow these exceptions? Rethrow them as some other arbitrary RuntimeException? Not allow types that may throw checked exception to be used inside a predicate?

Comment: @LBushkin The difference is having the ternary logic in the interface, or the implementation. Most of your predicates probably won't throw any exception. And, even if they do, it's clearly that, an *exception*. I'd rather document it in the implementation, or debug it later, as a runtime exception, than having `throws Exception` in the interface, and imposing a `try-catch` for every single predicate used.

Comment: Alternatively, swallow the exception and return a reasonable value. E.g.: test if a given file contains more than one line. The implementation will have to deal with `IOException` and maybe `FileNotFoundException`. I'd have it return `false` if the file does not exist, and throw a runtime exception if some error happens while reading, as you may not be able to tell the answer, by the time the `IOException` occurrs.

Answer (score 1):

Having `throws Exception` (it it's a checked exception) in an interface means you know under what condition such a checked exception should be thrown. That means that interface already has some knowledge of its implementation. Which should not be the case. Therefore I would go against any `throws Exception` in an interface. If an interface throws a checked `Exception` I would suggest simplifying it leaving exception logic to the implementation(s).

Comment: @LBuskin the reason to have throws Exception is to save the implementor the boilerplate of catching and converting things to some RuntimeException subclass in the situation where that adds no value. Basically, if the calling context is going to have to cope with "whatever the implementation throws back at it", then forcing the impl to catch and re-encapsulate everything isn't adding any value. Runner frameworks are an example of this. I.e., framework that runs components which can have very widely ranging behavior.

Answer (score 1):

A possible simple answer is - one should declare those exceptions which can be and typically will be processed during execution - i.e. to propagate, log or quit after an exception. Apart from an being error, I think that an exception is an unconditionally returned result type.

If the interface will be used internally, i.e. in a database, one possible way is to throw those exceptions that you specifically will/are processing.

If it's a public library, i.e. `ExecutorService`, some deep analysis can be required.

Example - JavaDoc from `ExecutorService`:

```
 /**
 * ...
 * @return the result returned by one of the tasks
 * @throws InterruptedException if interrupted while waiting
 * @throws TimeoutException if the given timeout elapses before
 *         any task successfully completes
 * @throws ExecutionException if no task successfully completes
 * @throws RejectedExecutionException if tasks cannot be scheduled
 *         for execution
 */
<T> T invokeAny(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks,
                long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
    throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException;
```

All these exceptions are domain-specific and one can may decisions based on their general meaning. So you can actually guess what they mean in the context of `invokeAny` method   given only this method's description.

This means that a couple of prototype implementations can be required to understand what  your domain is, what are the typical use cases and which typical errors can be thrown. I don't know how Java libraries were designed, in my case I do many refactorings for my prototype implementations and by doing this I understand the domain.

Some more points:

- Java's libraries document runtime exception which can be thrown, so it's perfectly fine to have them.
- Thus, implementing classes can throw a domain specific runtime exception if you forget one of the cases.
- One may document to wrap undeclared exceptions into one of the returned type exceptions, i.e. into `ExecutionException` - this is how it's done for `java.util.concurrent`.

Answer (score 0):

In general? In my experience given the complexities of an engineering issue, and given the options available in a given engineering context, the answer of greatest expeditious value is given highest priority.

Elegance is a question of opinion. However it seems most elegant to me to throw an custom SegmentException on add (if that's a possibility), and to try and minimize the possibility of Exception(s) in general.